# Service Console Output Via TCP Server

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have a Complex Service that i am working with, and as with all windows services, there is no Console to read any debug messages, or anything like that, so you would have to log all messages to a text file... i'm wanting to write in a small TCP Server (or UDP or NamedPipe doesn't really matter), where i can have a debug application...so basically, the service runs all the time and has this listener / server (Tcp or otherwise) and is always writing Debug messages to the server, if i need to debug the server, i should be able to connect to it using a TCP Client (or whatever protocol) and read any debug messages, or anything where i would typically use Console.WriteLine("Message");

i know this seems like a crazy idea, but it's something I've been considering and needed some input on...

my basic problem is that i can write a TCP Server into the Service, but i am unsure how to pass the messages to it all the time, or only when a client is connected, any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I am using C# and would like to stick to that language.

Comment: Suggestion: save yourself some time and effort and just use IIS and write a little ASP.Net for your "debug console".  IMHO...

Comment: that would be fantastic, sadly it is not an option.

Comment: Can you attach a debugger to the service process? Then you can just use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past, I've used a [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) for a similar monitoring program. It's an incredibly easy thing to create. And to communicate with it, I created a [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) in the service.

A good example of how to make those two work together is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294169/56778).