# Waiting for multiple TcpClients to have data available - WaitHandle or Thread.Sleep?

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, waithandle

I am writing a server application that will receive data from multiple TCP connections. We would like to be able to scale to ~200 connections. The first algorithm I wrote for this is as follows:

```
while (keepListening)
{
    foreach (TcpClient client in clientList)
    {
        if (!client.Connected)
        {
            client.Close();
            deleteList.Add(client);
            continue;
        }

        int dataAvail = client.Available;
        if (dataAvail > 0)
        {
            NetworkStream netstr = client.GetStream();
            byte[] arry = new byte[dataAvail];
            netstr.Read(arry, 0, dataAvail);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arry);
            try
            {
                CommData data = dataDeserializer.Deserialize(ms) as CommData;
                beaconTable.BeaconReceived(data);
            }
            catch
            { }
        }
    }

    foreach (TcpClient clientToDelete in deleteList)
        clientList.Remove(clientToDelete);
    deleteList.Clear();

    while (connectionListener.Pending())
        clientList.Add(connectionListener.AcceptTcpClient());

    Thread.Sleep(20);
}
```

This works fine, though I found that I have to add the Thread.Sleep to slow down the loop, otherwise it takes up an entire core, no matter how many or few connections there are. I was advised that Thread.Sleep is generally considered bad, so I looked for some alternatives. In a similar question to this, I was recommended to use BeginRead and BeginAccept using WaitHandles, so I wrote up an algorithm to do the same thing using that, and came up with this:

```
while (keepListening)
{
    int waitResult = WaitHandle.WaitAny(waitList.Select(t => t.AsyncHandle.AsyncWaitHandle).ToArray(), connectionTimeout);

    if (waitResult == WaitHandle.WaitTimeout)
        continue;

    WaitObject waitObject = waitList[waitResult];
    Type waitType = waitObject.WaitingObject.GetType();

    if (waitType == typeof(TcpListener))
    {
        TcpClient newClient = (waitObject.WaitingObject as TcpListener).EndAcceptTcpClient(waitObject.AsyncHandle);
        waitList.Remove(waitObject);

        byte[] newBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        waitList.Add(new WaitObject(newClient.GetStream().BeginRead(newBuffer, 0, bufferSize, null, null), newClient, newBuffer));

        if (waitList.Count < 64)
            waitList.Add(new WaitObject(connectionListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(null, null), connectionListener, null));
        else
        {
            connectionListener.Stop();
            listening = false;
        }
    }
    else if (waitType == typeof(TcpClient))
    {
        TcpClient currentClient = waitObject.WaitingObject as TcpClient;
        int bytesRead = currentClient.GetStream().EndRead(waitObject.AsyncHandle);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(waitObject.DataBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            try
            {
                CommData data = dataDeserializer.Deserialize(ms) as CommData;
                beaconTable.BeaconReceived(data);
            }
            catch
            { }
            byte[] newBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            waitList.Add(new WaitObject(currentClient.GetStream().BeginRead(newBuffer, 0, bufferSize, null, null), currentClient, newBuffer));
        }
        else
        {
            currentClient.Close();
        }

        waitList.Remove(waitObject);

        if (!listening && waitList.Count < 64)
        {
            listening = true;
            connectionListener.Start();
            waitList.Add(new WaitObject(connectionListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(null, null), connectionListener, null));
        }
    }
    else
        throw new ApplicationException("An unknown type ended up in the wait list somehow: " + waitType.ToString());
}
```

This also works fine, until I hit 64 clients. I wrote in a limit to not accept more than 64 clients because that's the maximum number of WaitHandles that WaitAny will accept. I can't see any good way around this limit, so I basically can't maintain more than 64 connections like this. The Thread.Sleep algorithm works fine with 100+ connections.

I also don't really like having to pre-allocate a receive array of arbitrary size rather than allocating it at the exact size of the received data after the data is received. And I have to give WaitAny a timeout anyways, or else it prevents the thread running this from Join-ing when I close the application if there are no connections. And it's just generally longer and more complex.

So why is Thread.Sleep the worse solution? Is there some way I can at least get the WaitAny version to handle more than 64 connections? Is there some completely different way of handling this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I'm a little confused why you're using `WaitHandles` at all with `BeginRead`. Just supply an `AsyncCallback`. That method will be called when the read completes. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6023264/56778 for an example. Also, check the related questions.

Comment: Good idea. I had initially dismissed using callbacks because it seemed too complex, but I tried it out and it actually is pretty simple. I'll post the code in a self-answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jim gave the obvious suggestion of using Async callbacks instead of WaitHandles. I initially thought that this would be too complex, but it got a lot simpler once I realized that I could pass a reference to the calling TcpListener or TcpClient in the state object. With that and a few changes for thread-safety, it's ready to go. It tests fine with over 100 connections and has no problem with exiting cleanly. I would still like an alternative, though, to having to pre-allocate the data buffer. Here's the code for anyone trying something similar:

```
public class NetworkReceiver : IDisposable
{
    private IReceiver beaconTable;
    private XmlSerializer dataDeserializer;
    private HashSet<TcpClient> ClientTable;
    private TcpListener connectionListener;
    private int bufferSize = 1000;

    public NetworkReceiver(IReceiver inputTable)
    {
        beaconTable = inputTable;
        dataDeserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CommData));

        ClientTable = new HashSet<TcpClient>();
        connectionListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, SharedData.connectionPort);
        connectionListener.Start();
        connectionListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ListenerCallback, connectionListener);
    }

    private void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        TcpListener listener = callbackResult.AsyncState as TcpListener;
        TcpClient client;

        try
        {
            client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(callbackResult);

            lock (ClientTable)
                ClientTable.Add(client);

            ClientObject clientObj = new ClientObject() { AsyncClient = client, Buffer = new byte[bufferSize] };
            client.GetStream().BeginRead(clientObj.Buffer, 0, bufferSize, ClientReadCallback, clientObj);

            listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ListenerCallback, listener);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void ClientReadCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
    {
        ClientObject clientObj = callbackResult.AsyncState as ClientObject;
        TcpClient client = clientObj.AsyncClient;

        if (!client.Connected)
            return;

        try
        {
            int bytesRead = client.GetStream().EndRead(callbackResult);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(clientObj.Buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                try
                {
                    CommData data;
                    lock (dataDeserializer)
                        data = dataDeserializer.Deserialize(ms) as CommData;
                    lock (beaconTable)
                        beaconTable.BeaconReceived(data);
                }
                catch
                { }

                client.GetStream().BeginRead(clientObj.Buffer, 0, bufferSize, ClientReadCallback, clientObj);
            }
            else
            {
                client.Close();
                lock (ClientTable)
                    ClientTable.Remove(client);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.GetType() == typeof(ObjectDisposedException) || ex.GetType() == typeof(InvalidOperationException))
                return;
            else
                throw;
        }
    }

    class ClientObject
    {
        public TcpClient AsyncClient;
        public byte[] Buffer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        connectionListener.Stop();
        foreach (TcpClient client in ClientTable)
            client.Close();
    }
}
```